# Gitlab CI Artifacts Permanently Moved Error 301?

Tags: java, maven, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I just finished setting up Gitlab Ci to use a Docker container with Maven 3 and Java 8 to build my project. The build successfully completes however when I try to save the generated jar file as an artifact, Docker tells me the artifact has been permanently moved....directly after finding the jar file.

This one has me scratching my head.

Here is my Giitlab CI yml file:

```
image: kaiwinter/docker-java8-maven

before_script:
    - apt-get update --fix-missing
    - apt-get install -y git
    - git clone -v https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/javafx-d3.git    /builds/external/javafxd3
    - cd /builds/external/javafxd3/javafx-d3
    - mvn install
    - cd /builds/external/myDemo


build:
 script: "mvn -B install"
 tags:
  - java8
  - maven3
 artifacts:
   paths:
    - target/*.jar
```

And this is the last few lines from the console from the Job.

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.547 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-06T17:58:06+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/462M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Uploading artifacts...
target/*.jar: found 1 matching files               
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=105 responseStatus=301 Moved Permanently status=301 Moved Permanently token=4pf6n8aT
WARNING: Retrying...                               
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=105 responseStatus=301 Moved Permanently status=301 Moved Permanently token=4pf6n8aT
WARNING: Retrying...                               
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=105 responseStatus=301 Moved Permanently status=301 Moved Permanently token=4pf6n8aT
FATAL: invalid argument                            
Job succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. Apparently the docker container, although it could ping the gitlab host, couldnt resolve the artifact-uploader domain name specified in the runner. I changed the runner config in /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml to the IP of the host machine, and the artifacts copied just fine.

Comment: Could you clarify which setting you changed?

Comment: @ThomasBoby It was in the "url" parameter of the "runners" section in the config.toml file

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html